# Pyspark / Databricks. Kolmogorov - Smirnov over time. Efficiently. In parallel

Tags: pyspark, parallel-processing, databricks, user-defined-functions, kolmogorov-smirnov

Hello StackOverflowers.

I have a pyspark dataframe that consists of a time_column and a column with values.
E.g.

```
+----------+--------------------+
|  snapshot|              values|
+----------+--------------------+
|2005-01-31| 0.19120256617637743|
|2005-01-31|  0.7972692479278891|
|2005-02-28|0.005236883665445502|
|2005-02-28|  0.5474099672222935|
|2005-02-28| 0.13077227571485905|
+----------+--------------------+
```

I would like to perform a KS test of each snapshot value with the previous one.

I tried to do it with a for loop.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def KS_for_one_snapshot(temp_df, snapshots_list, j, var = "values"):
  sample1=temp_df.filter(F.col("snapshot")==snapshots_list[j])
  sample2=temp_df.filter(F.col("snapshot")==snapshots_list[j-1]) # pick the last snapshot as the one to compare with

  if (sample1.count() == 0 or sample2.count() == 0 ):
    ks_value = -1  # previously "0 observations" which gave type error
  else:
    ks_value, p_value = ks_2samp(  np.array(sample1.select(var).collect()).reshape(-1)
                                 , np.array(sample2.select(var).collect()).reshape(-1)
                                 , alternative="two-sided"
                                 , mode="auto")



  return ks_value

results = []
snapshots_list = df.select('snapshot').dropDuplicates().sort('snapshot').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
for j in range(len(snapshots_list) - 1 ):
  results.append(KS_for_one_snapshot(df, snapshots_list, j+1))
results
```

But the data in reality is huge so it takes forever. I am using databricks and pyspark, so I wonder what would be a **more efficient way** to run it by **avoiding the for loop** and utilizing the available workers.

I tried to do it by using a udf but in vain.

Any ideas?

PS. you can generate the data with the following code.

```
from random import randint

    df = (spark.createDataFrame( range(1,1000), T.IntegerType())
          .withColumn('snapshot' ,F.array(F.lit("2005-01-31"), F.lit("2005-02-28"),F.lit("2005-03-30")  ).getItem((F.rand()*3).cast("int")))
          .withColumn('values', F.rand()).drop('value')
    )
```

***Update:***

I tried the following by using an UDF.

```
var_used = 'values'
data_input_1 = df.groupBy('snapshot').agg(F.collect_list(var_used).alias('value_list'))
data_input_2 = df.groupBy('snapshot').agg(F.collect_list(var_used).alias("value_list_2"))
windowSpec = Window.orderBy("snapshot")
data_input_2 = data_input_2.withColumn('snapshot_2', F.lag("snapshot", 1).over(Window.orderBy('snapshot'))).filter('snapshot_2 is not NULL')
data_input_final = data_input_final = data_input_1.join(data_input_2, data_input_1.snapshot == data_input_2.snapshot_2)

def KS_one_snapshot_general(sample_in_list_1, sample_in_list_2):
  
  if (len(sample_in_list_1) == 0 or len(sample_in_list_2) == 0 ):
    ks_value = -1  # previously "0 observations" which gave type error
  else:
    print('something')
    ks_value, p_value = ks_2samp(  sample_in_list_1
                                 , sample_in_list_2
                                 , alternative="two-sided"
                                 , mode="auto")
  
  return ks_value

import pyspark.sql.types as T
KS_one_snapshot_general_udf = udf(KS_one_snapshot_general, T.FloatType())
data_input_final.select( KS_one_snapshot_general_udf('value_list', 'value_list_2')).display()
```

Which works fine if the dataset (per snapshot) is small. But If I increase the number of rows then I end up with an error.
*PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)*

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I see you apply a `collect` in the `KS_for_one_snapshot`, does this mean the dataset is small enought per snapshot to fit in memory?

Comment: @Nithish Per snapshot indeed, it is small enough. Also, I dont know another way, as the function accepts numpy array only as input.